# Handling large response for rest API

Tags: java, rest, caching

So I have the following situation:

- Must connect to a rest api that responds with a large amount of data (100000 records/user).
- The application must connect to the API, retreive the data, pass the data to another application in a paginated way.

This means that if a request is done to the application, it will connect to a rest API, will retreive 100000 records but it must pass the records 100 at a time when requested.

The Rest API that returns the large data doesn't support pagination (nor it will).

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Reject the project ;) No, seriously. Does the application have the possibility to "cache" into a database?

Comment: Yea, an intermediate storage (like Redis) is pretty much the only sane thing to do here. What a well designed REST API for giving 100,000 records at once...

Comment: Intersting would then also be how frequently the data changes. Would be a nightmare if your "cache" would have to be considered dirty after each call ...

Comment: I guess you have no other option as going through the REST-API; you cannot request the underlying DB directly? I am asking because this is going to be an enormous performance nightmare. Not to mention the waste of energy , haha

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately we cannot skip the API. And yes, data will change quite often (a matter of hours).

Comment: Another interesting thing is that for the same request (a search between two dates), data might change so we cannot completely skip the API call even with a cache.. We can only do the caching, retrieve the data that we have from the cache and make sure we cache+send everything else that we don't yet have in our cache.

Comment: Hmm ... but you could split searches ... like a search of a span of 4 days you would split into a search for each of the days ... that would result at least in something that behaves like pagination. But I guess that's not the only criteria to search for , right?

Comment: This is actually a architecture/design question not a real programming challenge. How big is the average size in bytes of a response? How big is the average response time? Do you know the access pattern so you can estimate how many query results you need to cache to reach a certain response latency requirement of you service? How many servers will answer to queries? Can you direct the same query to the identical server or, maybe, do you need an intermediate caching layer?

Comment: @Fildor: the API behaves in the following way ->you can search for things between 02.02.2015 and 03.03.2016 but it will provide all data that has valability between those dates.
Meaning: it could give you data that is valid between 01.01.2014 and 03.03.2079. So this will not work. 

However there is an id for each row. Initially I though this might help...but the API doesn't know to return all data that has that id > X...

Comment: @cruftex:  
- average size might be 10Mb  
- highest response can be 130Mb  
- expected concurrency : don't yet know but the above data doesn't look too good.  
- The average response time of the API calculated at about 2 seconds (which is by the way alot) for 3000 records.  
- Access pattern: don't yet know.  
- No servers: will find out on Monday.  
- Same query: might return different responses for different users -> meaning it might return additional data if the same query is done in 5 minutes time even if the user searches by two dates (in the past)

Comment: I thought of a caching layer -> but at this point it seems more like a workaround than a real solution because I can cache all those records but somehow I am obliged to do the API request again to check for additional data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will use a cache as a solution until the API will be enhaced.